# Oracle case statement or condition

Tags: oracle

I'm a bit new to Oracle and not sure of which of the below is performant. While both of them give me the same results, I want advise as to which one is better.

```
(case
    when tax is null
      then charge
    when tax = 0
      then charge                     
    else tax end
) as tax,
```

or

```
(case
    when tax is null or tax = 0
      then charge
    else tax end
) as tax,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### They are same cost

you can see them with **explain plan**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could easily benchmark it, but I don't think it will make a big ifference.

I'd choose the latter because it is better to read.